# Localizing WebForms without excessively using meta:resourcekey

Tags: asp.net, localization, internationalization, culture

I was just given a project that needs to be localized.
I just ran into meta:resourcekey and how it's used in conjunction with local resource files.

My question is: do I have to do it this way?
Consider this example right off MSDN:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="DefaultText" 
       meta:resourcekey="Button1" />
```

If I'm reading this for the first time (which I am), I'd say "why specify `Button1` twice?"
If `<@ Page @>` already has `Culture` set to `auto`, and there are local resource files, go and find each control's local resources, if any, without having to do this double-mention for EVERY single control on the page.
I looked at a page we already have that does that and it just looks like clutter, if you ask me.

Am I missing something here?
Or is this method obsolete and there is a better way to do it?
All input (+/-) is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You can avoid "specifying twice" at the time of writing. Then you can write simple script (i.e. Perl script) that will add meta:resourceKey attribute to each tag; This could also externalize desired text by adding it resx file. I am not sure if there is no Visual Studio command or extension to do just that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that specifying the control identifier a second time in the `meta:resourcekey` attribute seems redundant, but it's there for a good reason.

Suppose you're maintaining an application localized in, say, 42 languages. Suppose translations for some of those languages are outsourced to, say, 6 different contractors.

Now imagine you absolutely have to change the `ID` of your button from `Button1` to `defaultButton`. What would be the best way to do that?

- Change the `ID` attribute, leave `meta:resourcekey` as it is, and be on your merry way, or
- Change the `ID` attribute, then modify dozens of resource files so they use the new `ID`, then give a call to all your contractors asking them to modify the resource files they provide you?

Comment: I agree with you on that one.  I'll take it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. However it doesn't explain why `meta:resourcekey` is mandatory for localization to work, instead of defaulting to the control ID when not specified.

Comment: @Medinoc, that's because localization is opt-in. Without the attribute, ASP.NET won't try to localize the element at all.